# Atmosphere, JBoss AS 7.1.1, Chrome issue

Tags: java, jboss, atmosphere

Got Atmosphere 1.0.0.beta1 setup and running with Jetty.  Straight forward easy and effective.

However when running on JBoss AS 7.1.1, it doesn't like the websocket transport and downgrades.  I see the following logs in Chrome's console (below)

When running against Jetty, it connects with the web socket transport and all is well.  For  some reason the downgrade doesn't fly with Chrome.  Works great in Firefox and IE9 both with jetty and jboss.

So HOW do I get the websocket transport working with JBoss.  Yes I googled and tried various things for an hour without avail.

Thanks.

```
Unexpected response code: 501 null:1
Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent). jquery.atmosphere.js:1867
Websocket closed, wasClean: false jquery.atmosphere.js:1867
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending jquery.atmosphere.js:1867
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending jquery.atmosphere.js:1867
TransportFailure, fall back is sse ecm-websocket.js:34
Invoking executeSSE jquery.atmosphere.js:1867
Using URL: http://srdevecm1:8080/ecm/ecm-ws/main?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=3b38258e-89a3-33cc-60d9-684956499835&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=sse&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json jquery.atmosphere.js:1867
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS 7 does not have a websockets implementation currently. There is a [implementation](https://github.com/mikebrock/jboss-websockets) that use JBossWeb, but haven't been committed upstream as of yet.